# C# calling c dll functions whose return type is struct* (I don't have the struct c code/definition)

Tags: c#, c, struct, dllimport

I have a library called MT7Trace.dll and its header MT7Trace.h. I would like to be able to use the functions included in this dll in c# code but I am not capable of importing them properly. Taking as an example these two functions:

```
MT7TRACE MT7TraceEnum MT7TraceCreateEnum (void);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceSensor MT7TraceGetNextSensor (MT7TraceEnum hEnumerator);
```

where:

```
typedef struct tagMT7TraceEnum * MT7TraceEnum;
```

My naive attempt so far has been as follows:

```
[DllImport("MT7Trace.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr MT7TraceCreateEnum(); //MT7TRACE MT7TraceEnum T7TraceCreateEnum (void);

[DllImport("MT7Trace.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr MT7TraceGetNextSensor (IntPtr hEnumerator);//MT7TRACE MT7TraceSensor MT7TraceGetNextSensor (MT7TraceEnum hEnumerator);
```

But when testing this imported functions:

```
private bool InitializeOneSensor()
{
    var hEnum = MT7TraceCreateEnum();

    var sensorCtr  = 0;
    MT7TraceSensor hSensor;
    while ((hSensor = MT7TraceGetNextSensor(hEnum)) != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // Do something else ..
        DllTraceReleaseSensor(hSensor);
        sensorCtr++;
    }
    DllTraceReleaseEnum(hEnum);
    return sensorCtr ==1;
}
```

where

```
using MT7TraceEnum    = System.IntPtr;
using MT7TraceSensor  = System.IntPtr;
```

I have have an exception:

> A call to PInvoke function
>   'Atracsys.Framework!Atracsys.MicroTouchDevice::MT7TraceGetNextSensor'
>   has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
>   the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
>   the target unmanaged signature.

I have seen some examples that explain how to create/recreate a struct to call a dll function with it but, in those the c struct definition was available somewhere:

```
struct XXX{
   type1 fiel1;
   type1 fiel1;
   ...

};
```

Thus, to call the dll function an equivalent c sharp structure was created and used to call it.

In my case I do not have the struct definition (as you can see looking at MT7Trace.h below)

Any suggestions?

This is the content of the MT7Trace.h code:

```
/*******************************************************************************
Copyright 2009 3M. All rights reserved.

Program Name:  MT7Trace
Module Name:   MT7Trace.h

Summary: Application interface for MT 7 Software Trace library

Description:
   This header file defines the application interface for the MT 7 Software
   Trace library. This interface allows an application to enumerate touch
   sensors and obtain traces from the sensors.

Notes:

*******************************************************************************/

#ifndef __MT7TRACE_H__
#define __MT7TRACE_H__

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

/******************************************************************************/
/* I N C L U D E   F I L E S                                                  */

/* Global Includes */

/* Project Includes */

/* Local Includes */

/******************************************************************************/
/* C O N S T A N T S                                                          */

#ifndef MT7TRACE
#if defined (WIN32) || defined (UNDER_CE)
#define MT7TRACE __declspec (dllimport)
#else
#define MT7TRACE
#endif
#endif


/******************************************************************************/
/* G L O B A L   D A T A   T Y P E S                                          */

typedef enum
{
   MT7TraceReason_Arrival = 1,
   MT7TraceReason_Departure = 2,
   MT7TraceReason_NewTrace = 3,
   MT7TraceReason_NewEvent = 4,
} MT7TraceReason;
typedef void (* MT7TraceCallback) (MT7TraceReason eReason, void * hItem,
                                   void * pvUserCode);
typedef enum
{
   MT7TraceEvent_Touchdown = 0,
   MT7TraceEvent_Drag = 1,
   MT7TraceEvent_Liftoff = 2,
} MT7TraceEventType;
typedef struct tagMT7TraceEnum * MT7TraceEnum;
typedef struct tagMT7TraceSensor * MT7TraceSensor;
typedef struct tagMT7TraceTrace * MT7TraceTrace;
typedef struct tagMT7TraceEvent * MT7TraceEvent;

/******************************************************************************/
/* P U B L I C   D A T A                                                      */


/******************************************************************************/
/* G L O B A L   D A T A                                                      */


/******************************************************************************/
/* G L O B A L   F U N C T I O N   P R O T O T Y P E S                        */


// Enumeration API
MT7TRACE MT7TraceEnum   MT7TraceCreateEnum      (void);
MT7TRACE unsigned int   MT7TraceGetEnumID       (MT7TraceEnum hEnumerator);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceEnum   MT7TraceCloneEnum       (MT7TraceEnum hEnumerator);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceSensor MT7TraceGetNextSensor   (MT7TraceEnum hEnumerator);
MT7TRACE void           MT7TraceReleaseEnum     (MT7TraceEnum hEnumerator);

// Sensor API
MT7TRACE unsigned int   MT7TraceGetSensorID         (MT7TraceSensor hSensor);
MT7TRACE const char *   MT7TraceGetSensorName       (MT7TraceSensor hSensor);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceSensor MT7TraceCloneSensor         (MT7TraceSensor hSensor);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceTrace  MT7TraceGetNextTrace        (MT7TraceSensor hSensor);
MT7TRACE void           MT7TraceSetSensorCallback   (MT7TraceSensor hSensor,MT7TraceCallback fnCallback,void * pvUserCode);
MT7TRACE void           MT7TraceReleaseSensor       (MT7TraceSensor hSensor);

// Trace API
MT7TRACE unsigned int   MT7TraceGetTraceID          (MT7TraceTrace hTrace);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceTrace  MT7TraceCloneTrace          (MT7TraceTrace hTrace);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceEvent  MT7TraceGetNextEvent        (MT7TraceTrace hTrace);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceEvent  MT7TraceGetPriorEvent       (MT7TraceTrace hTrace,unsigned int nOffset);
MT7TRACE void           MT7TraceSetNextEvent        (MT7TraceTrace hTrace,unsigned int nIndex);
MT7TRACE unsigned int   MT7TraceGetEventCount       (MT7TraceTrace hTrace);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceEvent  MT7TraceGetEvent            (MT7TraceTrace hTrace,unsigned int nIndex);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceSensor MT7TraceGetTraceSensor      (MT7TraceTrace hTrace);
MT7TRACE void           MT7TraceSetTraceCallback    (MT7TraceTrace hTrace,MT7TraceCallback fnCallback,void * pvUserCode);
MT7TRACE void           MT7TraceReleaseTrace        (MT7TraceTrace hTrace);

// Event API
MT7TRACE unsigned int       MT7TraceGetEventID      (MT7TraceEvent hEvent);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceEvent      MT7TraceCloneEvent      (MT7TraceEvent hEvent);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceEventType  MT7TraceGetEventType    (MT7TraceEvent hEvent);
MT7TRACE float              MT7TraceGetEventX       (MT7TraceEvent hEvent);
MT7TRACE float              MT7TraceGetEventY       (MT7TraceEvent hEvent);
MT7TRACE unsigned int       MT7TraceGetEventTime    (MT7TraceEvent hEvent);
MT7TRACE MT7TraceTrace      MT7TraceGetEventTrace   (MT7TraceEvent hEvent);
MT7TRACE void               MT7TraceReleaseEvent    (MT7TraceEvent hEvent);

// Monitor/Poll API
MT7TRACE int    MT7TracePoll                (void);
MT7TRACE int    MT7TraceStartMonitor        (void);
MT7TRACE void   MT7TraceStopMonitor         (void);
MT7TRACE void   MT7TraceSetArrivalCallback  (MT7TraceCallback fnCallback,void * pvUserCode);
MT7TRACE void   MT7TraceSetUniversalCallback(MT7TraceCallback fnCallback,void * pvUserCode);

/******************************************************************************/
/* G L O B A L   M A C R O S                                                  */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* ifndef __MT7TRACE_H__ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the unbalanced stack is caused by using the wrong calling convention. Change your `DllImport` attribute:

```
[DllImport("MT7Trace.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Comment: Thanks! This has solved the exceptions problem.

It also seems that I had not installed drivers properly thus, when calling the Dll functions I was having non-sense results!

Cheers,
Felix